# Selector function not being entered when observer is added

Tags: swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

In my first view controller, I post the notification with the following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("date"), object: formattedDate)
```

I then "receive" the notification in a second view controller with the following code:

```
func receiveNotification () {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didGetTheDate(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("date"), object: nil)
}

@objc 
func didGetTheDate(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("In did get date")
    date = notification.object as! String    
}
```

However, the function "didGetTheDate" never gets called.
I have triple checked that the function "receiveNotification" gets called as I have added print statements to check this.

Can somebody please help me with this.

Comment: Did you add the observer before posting the notification? I mean, receiveNotification() should be called before you post the notification from the ViewController 1. Also, you cannot release the ViewController 2 because the observer will be released

Comment: I added the observer after posting the notification. How do I receive a notification if the notification hasn't been posted yet?. What do you mean by "Also, you cannot release the ViewController 2 because the observer will be released". Sorry I am quite new to this

Comment: If you want to communicate events from one VC to another, you will need a Queue, in this case you can just create a Singleton with a list which you can call to see if there is a new "Date" event.   
For releasing VC 2 you should take a look at how memory works on iOS and ARC

Comment: Oh I just got it, thank you so much, I was stuck on this for hours. So an observer needs to be added first as it "Looks" for the post with the same NSNotification.Name.

Comment: Exactly, NSNotificacionCenter is a variation of the Observer Pattern, you can read about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm ( I will add this as answer for future users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNotificacionCenter` is a variation of the Observer Pattern, you can read about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)

This means that you will have to register an Observer before posting any notification. If you post anything before that, the `NSNotificationCenter` will look at the observer for `name` and will see that nobody is listening for it, thus nothing will happen.